# catkin_make_isolated fails with "--install-space /opt/ros/groovy"

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin-make-isolated, osx, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Environment) OSX 10.8.2, Groovy following [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source#groovy.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Source.Building_the_catkin_Packages).

```
$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install
```

seems to successfully build groovy desktop. [This workaround](http://answers.ros.org/question/54234/cant-build-python_orocos_kdl-on-osx/?answer=54241#post-id-54241) for `sip` related error worked.

However the following fails. The solution for `sip` above doesn't make any difference.

```
$ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install --install-space /opt/ros/groovy
:
ImportError: No module named sipconfig
```

[Full error output](http://pastebin.com/xsG40zW8).

What's wrong?

As a workaround I might be able to build first with 1st method then move the artifact to the different folder (under `/opt` in this case) but because script files generated by `catkin` contains absolute path it's cumbersome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59178/catkin_make_isolated-fails-with-%22--install-space-/opt/ros/groovy%22/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that most likely your 'sudo' environment does not have the sip module in its path. I bet if you do:

```
$ sudo bash
# ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install --install-space /opt/ros/groovy
```

That it would work.  Another solution would be to create the `/opt/ros` folder and then make it user writable therefore you will not have to use sudo every time:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /opt/ros
$ sudo chmod a+w /opt/ros
$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install --install-space /opt/ros/groovy
```

But honestly why install it to `/opt/ros/groovy`? Why not `~/groovy`?

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-03-25**:
Thanks, now trying. `/opt/ros` I thought is recommended in [wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source#groovy.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Source.Building_the_catkin_Packages).

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-03-26**:
There is a note here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source#groovy.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-Source.Building_the_catkin_Workspace but that just says if you "want to" the official lines don't tell you to do so. It is completely optional, there is no functional difference.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-03-27**:
Makes sense. Actually there seems to be still other issue when I use `sudo` other than the issue I noted (in my case `gencpp` complains) so I just use non-sudo env.